# how to represent REST API URL for update the number of likes of some post

Tags: rest

I am studying REST API.
I'm thinking about how to design the REST API for the following situations.

"If you click the Like button on a post, increase the number of likes on that post."

This corresponds to an UPDATE among CRUD. Right?
Then should I express the URL like this?

```
POST /post/{post_id}/likes
```

But there also will be situations like this.

If you press the "Like" button again, Decrease the likes again.'

In that case, would it be appropriate to send a request with this data in the payload?

```
POST /post/{post_id}/likes

{
countup: False // decrease likes
}
```

I coudn't think of anything better than this,
but I feel strange that this isn't a very good idea.
I want to design the API to match the convention.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me some better ideas.

Comment: In general, REST is just like using the regular Web but instead of humans interacting with those "pages" (a.k.a. resources) applications are doing it. How you design the interaction doesn't differ much from how you'd design the interaction on the human Web. Your outlined approach doesn't violate any HTTP standards nor REST constraints. As such it may be a viable solution. Keep in mind though that REST is more than just a simple CRUD Web-API. As a starting source I'd recommend to watch [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc) by Jim Webber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you click the Like button on a post, increase the number of likes
> on that post. If you press the "Like" button again, Decrease the likes
> again.

Pressing the like button and adding a toggle is an UI thing.

> on a post increase the number of likes or decrease the likes

If it would be operations I would do `increaseLikesForPost()`, `decreaseLikesForPost()`. What is hidden here that we usually add the `session.userid` as a parameter to know which user like the post later, not just increasing the number of like, so what really happens here is `increaseLikesForPost(actualUser)`, which does not make much sense in this context. It would be normally just `actualUser.like(post)` or `post.isLikedBy(actualUser)`. Since we use the API from the viewpoint of the `post` it is better to use the latter one.

So how do we translate this: `post.isLikedBy(actualUser)` or this: `postIsLikedBy(post, actualUser)` to the language of HTTP methods and an URIs?

A possible solution is `POST|PUT /api/posts/:postid/likes/:actualuserid` and `DELETE /api/posts/:postid/likes/:actualuserid`. If you don't want to add session related data to the URIs like `actualuserid`, then it is better to do `POST|PUT /api/posts/:postid/like` and `DELETE /api/posts/:postid/like` and get the `actualuserid` from the `Authorzation` header.